# How to record desktop screen in electron app using angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, electron, screen-recording

I am trying to record screen using angular

in `app.component.ts`

```
async recordScreen() {
    let stream = await navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
    console.log(stream)
}
```

in `main.js`

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 800,
     height: 600,
     autoHideMenuBar: true,
     webPreferences: {
         webSecurity: false,
         nodeIntegration: true,
         experimentalFeatures: true,
         allowRunningInsecureContent: true
     }
})
```

> TypeError: navigator.getDisplayMedia is not a function

**More detail**

When I run angular (without `Electron`) and enable flag `Experimental Web Platform features` in a browser, it `navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })` works fine

but ... with `Electron`, I've told already that what I am facing.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead, it works for me:

```
let stream = navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
```

Comment: `VS Code` is throwing error under `getDisplayMedia`, that's why failing to compile the project

Comment: tried to use as `(navigator.mediaDevices as any).getDisplayMedia({ video: true })` but getting error `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia is not a function`

Comment: Yea there is compile error something, because it's changed. You can try `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});`  there is no compile errors for that one, but not sure if it work for screen sharing.
Also you can read more about this update (getDisplayMedia used to live on navigator but was recently moved to navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) here -> https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/getdisplaymedia-now-available-in-adapter-js/